# How to use Intent Service,Broadcast Receiver properly in android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I have string array and, finding distance from current location to each area in array in background,

but my app is freezing and want to implement Intent Service, i tryied following code using many online tutorials but my intent service class is never called, which mistake m i doing? plz suggest me anything wch'll helpful to me,

my manifest file

```
 <service android:name=".ServiceGoogle.MyIntentService" android:enabled="true" /> 
 <receiver android:name=".ServiceGoogle.MyIntentReceiver">
    </receiver>
```

my mainActivity method

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
private void updateUI() {
       if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
        String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
        String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter(MyIntentReceiver.PROCESS_RESPONSE);
        intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        receiver=new MyIntentReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver,intentFilter);

        Intent myIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyIntentService.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("strAreas",strAreas);
        myIntent.putExtra("lat",lat);
        myIntent.putExtra("lng",lng);
        startService(myIntent);
}}
}
```

My IntentService class

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService{
           protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                lat, longt, 1);
        if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }
            currentLocation = sb.toString();
            for (int i = 0; i < strAreas.length; i++) {
                distanceHashList.put(strAreas[i],getLocationFromAddress(strAreas[i],this));
                }
            returnList();

            Intent intentBroadcast=new Intent(this,MyIntentReceiver.class);
            intentBroadcast.putExtra("CurrentLocation",currentLocation);
            intentBroadcast.putStringArrayListExtra("DistanceList", distanceAreas);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intentBroadcast);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to connect to Geocoder", e);
    }
}
}
```

MyReceiver

```
public class MyIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    currentlocation=intent.getStringExtra("CurrentLocation");
    distanceAreas=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("DistanceList");
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: does it have to use an external service? knowing start and end point lat/lon you can simply compute Haversine distance between two points: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Comment: Have you [defined your `IntentService` in your manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html#DefineManifest)?

Comment: no, thanks MH , i will let u know after define it.

Comment: I added service and receiver in manifest file, still my IntentService class is never called why?